# AWS: how to get the instance status check state, not state

Tags: amazon-web-services

The aws console show two columns State and Status Checks, when an instance is launching. A state of Running is not a true reflection of state because the Status Checks could fail.

Anyone have any examples of .net C# code to check the Status Check state?

The closest I have is this:

```
 var request = new DescribeInstanceStatusRequest();
        request.InstanceId = insts.Select(i => i.InstanceId).ToList();
        DescribeInstanceStatusResponse response = ec2Client.DescribeInstanceStatus(request);

        InstanceStatus instanceStatus = response.DescribeInstanceStatusResult.InstanceStatus[0];
        Console.WriteLine("Availability zone - " + instanceStatus.AvailabilityZone);
        Console.WriteLine("Instance State Code - " + instanceStatus.InstanceState.Code);
        Console.WriteLine("Instance State Name - " + instanceStatus.InstanceState.Name);

        foreach (InstanceStatusEvent statusEvent in instanceStatus.InstanceStatusEvent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event Code - " + statusEvent.Code);
            Console.WriteLine("Event Description - " + statusEvent.Description);
            Console.WriteLine("Earliest Scheduled Start Time - " + statusEvent.NotBefore);
            Console.WriteLine("Latest Scheduled End Time - " + statusEvent.NotAfter);
        }
```

But that just gives the State, not the Status Checks.

Comment: What does the current code print?

Comment: It prints "running", but this is not what I need, I need the "Status Check" field state because those could fail and the instance init would have gone wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look deeper into the InstanceStatus object. The status checks are in the `InstanceStatusDetail` and the `SystemStatusDetail` properties. Here is a snippet that gets that information for you:

```
        var status = result.InstanceStatus[0];
        Console.WriteLine("Instance Status = " + status.InstanceStatusDetail.Status);
        Console.WriteLine("Instance Status Detail Name = " + status.InstanceStatusDetail.Detail[0].Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Instance Status Detail Status = " + status.InstanceStatusDetail.Detail[0].Status);
        Console.WriteLine("System Status = " + status.SystemStatusDetail.Status);
        Console.WriteLine("System Status Detail Name = " + status.SystemStatusDetail.Detail[0].Name);
        Console.WriteLine("System Status Detail Status = " + status.SystemStatusDetail.Detail[0].Status);
```

Comment: + Even knowing where to look, it's a bit of a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Lucee](https://lucee.org/) (cfml) I got it like this:

```
<cfset var DescribeInstanceStatusRequest = CreateObject('java','com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.DescribeInstanceStatusRequest', jarLocation).init()>

<cfset var describeInstanceStatusRequest = DescribeInstanceStatusRequest.withInstanceIds([arguments.instanceId])>

<cfset var statusresult = ec2client.describeInstanceStatus(describeInstanceStatusRequest).getInstanceStatuses()[1].getInstanceStatus().getDetails()[1].getStatus()>
```

this (statusresult) gives "passed" if the server has passed all checks.

note: coldfusion handles arrays differently so if for example you were translating back to java you would use [0] instead of [1](https://lucee.org/).

If you only want the status: running, stopped etc

```
<cfset var result = ec2client.describeInstanceStatus(describeInstanceStatusRequest).getInstanceStatuses()[1].getInstanceState().getName()>
```